# Android Tasksnapshot getDownloadUrl() different token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem when I upload an image to firebase.

When I Upload the image I get one taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() token, and when I look in firebase storage there is a diffrent token key. I can't figure out where my problem is, and it is not every time I get the error (about 30 % of the time).

Hope you can help me.

**My upload method:**

```
 public void uploadImage(Context context, Activity activity) {
    String authorities = activity.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
    File f = new File(MainActivity.imagesPath + String.valueOf(uploadToiletId) + "_" + uploadTimeStamp + ".png");
    Log.i("HANDLERTAG", "file: " + f.getPath());
    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authorities, f);
    Log.i("HANDLERTAG", "image: " + imageUri.getPath());
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    try {

        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() / 4, bitmap.getHeight()/ 4, true);
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
        byte[] dataBAOS = baos.toByteArray();
        final String timeStamp = FormatHelper.getCurrentDateTimeString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
        StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child(String.valueOf(uploadToiletId)).child(timeStamp + ".png");
        imagesRef.putBytes(dataBAOS).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.i("CAMERATAG", "Billede uploadet");
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Log.i("DOWNLOAD_URL",String.valueOf(downloadUrl));
                HashMap<String, String> UploadImageMap = new HashMap<>();
                UploadImageMap.put("Url", downloadUrl.toString());
                UploadImageMap.put("UserId", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                databaseRef.child(DB_TABLE_TOILETS)
                        .child(String.valueOf(uploadToiletId))
                        .child("Images")
                        .child(timeStamp).setValue(UploadImageMap);
                databaseRef.child(DB_TABLE_USERS)
                        .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child("Images")
                        .child(String.valueOf(uploadToiletId))
                        .child(timeStamp).setValue(UploadImageMap);
            }
        });
        imagesRef.putBytes(dataBAOS).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.i("CAMERATAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.i("CAMERATAG", "Noget gik galt med billede");
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(context, "Upload complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("HANDLERTAG", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Debug shows token key from my app in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cCDQ.png)

Token key: token=b23e8ab1-8322-46cf-889e-4f276fb2c242

[Token from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgbGM.png)

Token key from firebase: token=e5b84bed-7226-4af3-b01b-e31cf03e7d8b

Comment: What´s the error?

Comment: There is no error, i just get different tokens i think it's an outdated key that get's uploaded and i really do not know why.

Comment: Did you generate the download url from the firebase console?

Comment: No, it happens in: onSuccess with this code:  Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting your storage to read true?

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This way users can read without being logged in, but has to be logged in to actually write to your storage.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem.